# Fatal Git error when switching branch

Tags: git

Error message:

> fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing

How to get past this Git checkout error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By explicitly specifying “`git checkout HEAD $blah`” instead of just saying “`git checkout $blah`”, assuming you did want to check out a file.

You don’t say what you were trying nor what you typed, however, so no one can give you anything but a blind guess.

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter this message, it is because I have tried to do `git checkout -f $blah`, expecting to throw away local changes, as described in `git checkout --help`.

Instead, I use `rm $blah && git checkout $blah` to throw away local changes.

Comment: I had to do the same thing when trying to --track a branch in a directory that was already --tracking another branch.  Still not sure how to track two branches in one directory.