# Git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches

Tags: git, git-checkout, remote-branch

My problem is related to [Fatal Git error when switching branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180064).

I try to fetch a remote branch with the command

```
git checkout -b local-name origin/remote-name
```

but I get this error message:

> fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
>   Did you intend to checkout 'origin/remote-name' which can not be resolved as commit?

If I manually create a branch and then pull the remote branch, it works, just as making a new clone and checking the branch out.

Why does it not work on the repository I work with?

Comment: what has changed since the first instance of that command (triggering the error message) ?

Comment: git init git fetch git fetch git://blabla.com/dir1/Project.git

Answer (score 747, accepted):

I believe this occurs when you are trying to checkout a remote branch that your local git repo is not aware of yet.  Try:

```
git remote show origin
```

If the remote branch you want to checkout is under "New remote branches" and not "Tracked remote branches" then you need to fetch them first:

```
git remote update
git fetch
```

Now it should work:

```
git checkout -b local-name origin/remote-name
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me, not the above arbitrary answer.

Comment: That should be "git fetch REPOSITORY_NAME" to get all of the branches on that repository.

Comment: not necessarily. `git fetch` will get all of the branches from all remote repos.

Comment: @Michael sometimes you need to specify the remotes name like @Mike noted.

Comment: In case anyone else struggles with the utter craziness of all this:    
  git fetch origin/branchname
Is _not_ the same as git fetch. The former simply results in "new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)" displaying in a column visible via git remote show origin.

Comment: @Mike Thomsen: your comment has been more helpful to me than the "solution". Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me but I just checked it out, without the "-b" for new branch.

Comment: Matt's answer using git checkout <branchname> is simpler.

Comment: If you still get the same error after all these steps like I did, try Rare Pleasure's "alternate syntax" git fetch origin remote_branch_name:local_branch_name - it worked when all else failed for me

Comment: If you are trying to do this for a remote that you explicitly added (so anything *other than origin*) you will need to do `git remote update` before your fetch will fetch that remote. Otherwise you get messages like `Did you intend to checkout 'upstream-repo/master' which can not be resolved as commit?` Please add this to the answer and save people hours worth of reading the same answers that only work for origin.

Comment: You should mention that the tab-key completion doesn't print out the apostrophe in the branch name, and that can be a reason it doesn't find it.

Comment: i just do a `git pull` to make sure my local git knows about all the remote branches being tracked, and then `checkout -b` with the --track command.

Comment: I got into this state from a repo clone. The git remote update worked. The git fetch did NOT work until I had checked out a remote tracking branch. After that git fetch worked.

Comment: after I `git svn clone --std-layout ...`, I have no git remotes only a block of `svn-remote` in my git config. this causes any remote op to fail. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 152):

Alternate syntax,

```
git fetch origin remote_branch_name:local_branch_name
```

Comment: This worked for me. My remote branch name isn't origin. I don't know if that makes a difference as I have been drinking vodka.

Comment: This is not just an alternate syntax, but can work when git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name does not work

Comment: omg! fnx! u saved me from a headache! git remote update && git fetch didnt work fo me - a didnt see others branches..

Comment: This also fixed my problem when running "git checkout --track origin/remote-branch", which originally gave the same error as OP's before the fix. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me after running also the validated answer.

Comment: This helped for me when started from an incomplete clone, i.e. the one with `--depth` specification.

Comment: Yes, I suspect the `--depth` qualifier for the original clone may be at fault here. I had success with `git fetch remote_branch_name:local_branch_name` but all other advice failed.

Comment: This doesn't give an error message but it also doesn't associate the local branch with the remote branch as with `git checkout -b <local-branch> --track <remote>/<remote-branch>`  and it doesn't set the current branch to `<local-branch>`.  So it's not a replacement for `git checkout -b <local-branch> --track <remote>/<remote-branch>` at all.  It just updates the remote tracking branches and creates <local-branch>.

Answer (score 48):

After having tried most of what I could read in this thread without success, I stumbled across this one:
[Remote branch not showing up in "git branch -r"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319968/remote-branch-not-showing-up-in-git-branch-r/12320930#12320930)

It turned out that my .git/config file was incorrect. After doing a simple fix all branches showed up.

Going from

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://stash.server.com/scm/EX/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://stash.server.com/scm/EX/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Did the trick

Comment: That's indeed an odd configuration. It tells git to only fetch the master branch from the remote.

Comment: I would vote it up 10 times if I could! - this seems to be some thing that new git does when cloning

Comment: I had the same problem, it was driving me crazy. Anyone not seeing remote branches, please check this!!

Comment: Thank god for your answer :)

Comment: Mind = blown! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is helpful or exactly relevant to your question, but if you are trying to fetch and checkout only a **single** branch from the remote repository, then the following git commands will do the trick:

```
url= << URL TO REPOSITORY >>
branch= << BRANCH NAME >>

git init
git remote add origin $url
git fetch origin $branch:origin/$branch
git checkout -b $branch --track origin/$branch
```

Answer (score 11):

none of the above worked for me. My situation is slightly different, my remote branch is not at **origin**. but in a different repository.

```
git remote add remoterepo GIT_URL.git
git fetch remoterepo
git checkout -b branchname remoterepo/branchname
```

tip: if you don't see the remote branch in the following output `git branch -v -a` there is no  way to check it out.

Confirmed working on 1.7.5.4

Comment: arf, just realize VirtualStaticVoid had the same solution!

Comment: +1 for `git branch -v -a`: I had an incorrectly configured remote that said `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/master/*` even though the remote was called `upstream`.

Answer (score 8):

For me what worked was:

```
git fetch
```

Which pulls all the refs down to your machine for all the branches on remote. Then I could do

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

and that worked perfectly. Similar to the top voted answer, but a little more simple.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there is no remote branch named remote-name, but that you've inadvertently created a local branch named origin/remote-name.

Is it possible you at some point typed:

```
git branch origin/remote-name
```

Thus creating a local branch named origin/remote-name?  Type this command:

```
git checkout origin/remote-name
```

You'll either see:

```
Switched to branch "origin/remote-name"
```

which means it's really a mis-named local branch, or

```
Note: moving to "origin/rework-isscoring" which isn't a local branch
If you want to create a new branch from this checkout, you may do so
(now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
  git checkout -b
```

which means it really is a remote branch.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very intuitive but this works well for me ...

```
  mkdir remote.git & cd remote.git & git init
  git remote add origin $REPO
  git fetch origin $BRANCH:refs/remotes/origin/$BRANCH
```

THEN run the git branch --track command ...

```
  git branch --track $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I had a typo and my remote branch didn't exist

Use `git branch -a` to list remote branches

Answer (score 1):

Could your issue be linked to this other SO question ["checkout problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499316/git-plugin-for-hudson-checkout-problem)?

i.e.: a problem related to:

- an old version of Git
- a curious checkout syntax, which should be: `git checkout -b [<new_branch>] [<start_point>]`, with  `[<start_point>]` referring to the name of a commit at which to start the new branch, and `'origin/remote-name'` is not that.
  (whereas [`git branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) does support a start_point being the name of a remote branch)

Note: what the [checkout.sh script](http://github.com/git/git/blob/8c4e4ef0f575cd60fb4bb6a70305fcb0ed85da6a/git-checkout.sh) says is:

```
  if test '' != "$newbranch$force$merge"
  then
    die "git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing$hint"
  fi
```

It is like the syntax  git checkout -b [] [remote_branch_name] was both renaming the branch and resetting the new starting point of the new branch, which is deemed incompatible.

Comment: The problem is solved. git checkout -b local-name remote/remote-branch does actually work

Comment: Interesting, what has changed since the first instance of that command (triggering the error message) ?

Answer (score 1):

After fetching a zillion times still added remotes didn't show up, although the blobs were in the pool. Turns out the **--tags** option shouldn't be given to `git remote add` for whatever reason. You can manually remove it from the .git/config to make git fetch create the refs.