# Remote branch is not showing up in "git branch -r"

Tags: git

I have been pushing to a remote Bitbucket repository and recently a colleague has pushed a new branch he created to the same repository.

I'm trying to fetch the changes he uploaded.

```
 $ git branch -a
 * master
 localbranch1
 localbranch2
 remotes/origin/master
```

> $ git branch -r
>   origin/master

In the web UI for Bitbucket I can see the branch he has made. How can I do this?

Next try:

```
$ git fetch bitbucket
Password for 'https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org':
From https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

If the branch he created is called **new_branch_b** should I be expecting to see the following?

```
$ git branch -r
origin/master
origin/new_branch_b
```

Third try:

```
$ git remote update
Fetching bitbucket
Password for 'https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org':
From https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git branch -r
  origin/master
```

Fourth try:

```
[remote "bitbucket"]
url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

I called the remote `bitbucket` rather than origin (at least that's what I recall; I set it up a while ago)

Fifth try:

I updated the Bitbucket remote configuration as per [kan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319968/remote-branch-is-not-showing-up-in-git-branch-r/12320930#12320930):

> $ git config -e

```
[remote "bitbucket"]
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bitbucket/*
```

For most people it will be called origin:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Afterwards,

```
$ git remote update

Fetching bitbucket
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org':
remote: Counting objects: 48, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
remote: Total 35 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (35/35), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/user/repo
 * [new branch]      branch_name1 -> origin/branch_name1
 * [new branch]      branch_name2    -> origin/branch_name2
```

.... and so on.

I think `git fetch origin` would also work for `git remote update`.

Comment: Cool, but maybe it had more sense to use `refs/remotes/bitbucket/*` instead of `refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: Thanks, duly noted about the naming consistency. It probably make more sense to change bitbucket to origin though! Convention and all that :)

Comment: `git fetch origin` does the job

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The `remote` section also specifies fetch rules. You could add something like this into it to fetch all branches from the remote:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

(Or replace `origin` with `bitbucket`.)

Please read about it here: *[10.5 Git Internals - The Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)*

Comment: This fixed my ongoing branching issue in Git that I had for weeks. Suddenly all the git remote update stuff actually started working. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, it looked like: `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` for me. Replacing `master` with `*` fixed my problem.

Comment: The file you need to edit is `.git/config`

Comment: This is very usefull if you have converted a shallow clone to an unshallow.

Comment: @kan Do you know why this sometimes happens? It just happen to me when `git clone` a project. I don't recall having done anything special with my local git.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Not sure... never happened to me unexpectedly. Is it possible that `clone` was interrupted and then resumed? Or something else has accesed repo concurrently?

Comment: @kan it's possible that the connection was interrupted.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter in my case, I think it was due to cloning with --single-branch maybe?  Still odd that fetch mechanics were modified... that's never happened when I use --single-branch clones in the past.

Comment: @CCJ I always use git from the command line and I have never used `--single-branch`.

Answer (score 313):

Update your remote if you still haven't done so:

```
$ git remote update
$ git branch -r
```

Comment: I'm using the GitHub client on Win and sometimes it doesn't update the remote branches. The first line "git remote update" works like a charm. Easy & clean

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: I think I had aleady successfully fetched the branch but just needed to see it listed with `git branch -r`.  On https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch it says "Option -r causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option -a shows both local and remote branches". `git remote update` fetches all branches of all remotes listed in `git remote -v`.

Comment: After running this I was able to run ```git checkout origin/master``` and then branched off of that detached head to my master branch ```git branch master; git checkout master```

Comment: Works for me.  Sure seems like Visual Studio should have this as a right click option on the remotes/origin folder in the Branches UI.

Answer (score 107):

If you clone with the `--depth` parameter, it sets `.git/config` not to fetch all branches, but only master.

You can simply omit the parameter or update the configuration file from

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: you can edit the configuration with `git config -e`

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue. It seems the easiest solution is to just remove the remote, readd it, and fetch.

Comment: ```git remote -v``` will show you your remotes so you can get hold of the url, ```git remote rm origin``` will remove it, ```git remote add origin <url>``` will re-add it.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a git submodule which somehow, did not fetch any remote branch than master. Removing and adding it again solved it.

Comment: worked for me, but now I get a warning `warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`

Comment: It's frustrating how often with git config issues the best solution is to delete something and start over.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, `git branch -a` and `git branch -r` do *not* show you all remote branches, if you haven't executed a "git fetch".

`git remote show origin` works consistently all the time. Also `git show-ref` shows all references in the Git repository. However, it works just like the `git branch` command.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just write `git checkout BRANCH_NAME` and it will create one locally and link it to the one on the origin

you should get this message prompted:
Branch 'BRANCH_NAME' set up to track remote branch 'BRANCH_NAME' from 'origin'.

Answer (score 0):

solution if you have trouble getting update to your server cloud computing platform or any something similar:

1. modify the git config file `/path/your_project/.git/config`
   from

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
   url = https://github.com/company_name/your_project.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```

   to

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
   url = git@github.com:company_name/your_project.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```
2. save changes
3. then run `git remote update`
4. check remote branch `git branch -r`
5. checkout branch `git checkout origin/branch-name`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a git repo that was checked-out using Bamboo, the URL that Bamboo uses is not the same as the original repo.  After doing every single suggestion in this question, I did `git config -e` and found the URL for `[remote "origin"]` and fixed the `url` setting so that it matched the URL I have been using in my personal workspace.

Before:

```
url = file:///home/agent/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache/71efa04b5e7c457ab86f97a26aa286d9258556fb
```

After:

```
url = http://bitbucket.mycompany.com:7990/scm/seq/myrepo.git
```