# Git Branches NOT Showing in "git branch" after Pull or Fetch but "git checkout" works ...?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-remote, git-fetch

After committing my latest work on a new branch `branchname` to my local git repo on machine A, I pushed that work to my gitlab remote repo with

```
$ git push origin branchname
```

The `master` branch was already in sync with the remote repo. All branches showed up on the remote repo on my gitlab list.

I later went to machine B. I first did a

```
$ git pull origin master
```

and master was updated, but my new `branchname` didn't show up when I typed `git branch`, nor did another branch that I new existed in the history tree. I went to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373277/git-sync-local-repo-with-remote-one) and followed the directions from the first answer. Another 'git branch' still did not show my other branches. On a whim, I simply tried to do

```
$ git checkout branchname
```

and it was there and checked out fine. A `git branch` command then showed master and branchname in my list of branches. I did the same thing with another branch, and it too then showed up in the branch list after a `git branch` command.

Is this normal git behavior for such operations? The main thing I am wondering is if you pull or fetch from a remote repo to update a local repo that had to know previous knowledge of branches on the remote, why don't they show up during a `git branch` command? And, why can I check them out when I couldn't see them after a `git branch`?

This saga is similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319968/remote-branch-not-showing-up-in-git-branch-r) one, but my branches were actually there and just NOT showing following git branch commands until I checked them out.

Comment: `git branch -a` shows you both remote and local branches and `git branch` shows only local branch. In machine B, `branchname` does not exists as local branch before `git checkout branchname` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ git branch     # only local branches
* master
```

In machine B, `branchname` does not exists as local branch before `git checkout branchname` command, so the list shows only `master`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout branchname
$ git branch
  master
* branchname
```

See all remote and local branches.

```
$ git branch -a   # remote and local branches
$ git branch -r   # remote branches only
```

**Note:** here, `git checkout branchname` actually finds a local branch named `branchname`. If found, then just checkout to that branch, but if not found then it searches in remote branch lists (e.g. `origin/branchname` ). If found, then create a local branch `branchname` with the same history of `origin/branchname`.

Comment: Thanks Sajib. I had done these experiments, but your answer and kowsky's explanations helped me to understand git's philosophy in this particular scenario much better.

Comment: I use git branch and it show all branch name except active branch name (with the * symbol). Why?

Comment: Thanks Sajib. It made things easy for me.

Answer (score 3):

`git branch`, without any parameters, only shows your local branches. When you `fetch`, information about your remote branches is updated, but it will only be shown when you use `git branch -r` (only remote branches) or, as @SajibKhan suggested, `git branch -a` (all remote and local branches).

So yes, this is intended behaviour. You can check them out since git recognizes the remote branch and sets up a new local branch that automatically is set up to track the remote branch.

Comment: Thanks kowsky. My further experiments confirmed your explanations. I just did not understand the git philosophy in this particular scenario. Makes sense now.