# Checkout branch on different remote

Tags: git, branch

I have a repo that has another remote `upstream` besides `origin`. I can do `git checkout origin/master`, but when I run `git checkout upstream/master`, I get:

```
error: pathspec 'upstream/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

This does not work either:

```
$ git fetch upstream
From https://github.com/getsentry/sentry
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git co -b asdf --track upstream/master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'asdf' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

How to check out branches on `upstream` remote as I do on `origin` remote? My git version is 2.1.2.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Just fetch the refs from the remote (this will fetch all branch, commit, refs etc for the upstream repo)

```
git fetch upstream
```

After this, checkout the needed branch (this creates a local copy of the branch)

```
git checkout -b <branchname> --track upstream/<branchname>
```

Now if you want to pull the changes in this branch in future, all you need to do is

```
git pull upstream <branchname>
```

---

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614996/1860929), try doing an explicit fetch on the branch name:

```
git fetch upstream master:branch_name
```

Comment: Does not work: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'asdf' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be resolved as commit?`.

Comment: @fossilet Can you check if `git fetch upstream master:branch_name` works for you? Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1614996/1860929

Comment: @fossilet Not sure why. Had tried googling this earlier, but couldn;t figure out. Might be a bug with the git version

Comment: How do I push the branch I made tracking upstream back to origin?

Comment: I got `fatal: 'upstream/develop' is not a commit and a branch 'develop' cannot be created from it`

Answer (score 11):

If you just added the remote, you'll need to `fetch` it so that Git knows which branches are available:

```
git fetch upstream master
```

After this you can do

```
git checkout upstream/master
```

without any issues.

Comment: Would this incorporate changes from upstream/master to origin/master? This isn't wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `fetch` not `pull`. Thanks.

Comment: After the fetch? That's surprising, since I definitely just tried this on my `git` and it works fine...can you post what steps you're using?

Comment: Yes, you can checkout `upstream/master`, but you will be in 'detached head' state.  If you want it to behave like you expect a branch to behave, you have to  make it a tracking branch like @mu wrote.

Answer (score 2):

In more concise way (I'm using `git` 2.28), you can say

```
git fetch upstream
```

and then

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> --guess
```

where the `--guess` flag checks if a branch corresponding to `<branch_name>` exists on any of the remotes and tracks the corresponding remote ([docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---guess)).

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below steps,

Step 01: add new remote using below add command

> git remote add testRemote https://repourl.git

Step 02: set the url as remote

> git remote set-url testRemote https://repourl.git

Step 03: to pull the branches from new repo

> git pull

Step 04: switch to new branch

> git checkout branchFromNewremote

Then you can create new branch from the current branch

Comment: I'm not sure this will work: can you really add a new remote also called `origin`? does `git pull` without an argument really pull from the new remote? And in your `git checkout` command, OP was getting an error doing `git checkout upstream/master`, can you explain how you avoid that?

Comment: your are right it wont work if we have already remote name as origin. Sorry there is a typo just corrected. Since we are setting new remote with "git remote set-url" git pull will try to pull all the branches from new remote and will help to switch to new branch from testRemote.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo. For the `git pull`, I'm still not convinced: in my experience, it pulls only from the default remote, which is going to be origin if you're one a branch tracking something origin when you run it. I just tested your instructions and `git pull` answered "Already up to date." You really need `git fetch testRemote` instead, like in the accepted answer.

Comment: To be honest, and sorry if I sound mean, but I'm not sure what you're trying to add to the accepted answer. I appreciate your efforts, but it's important to test solutions you propose here, and make sure new answers to old questions add something novel, or simpler, or better in some way that you can explain in your answer.

Comment: once you add new remote you must switch to new remote using set-url, this will point to your new remote. Post that if you want to checkout new branch under current remote pls do a git pull to fetch all the branches from current remote. You cant see new branches under current remote until you do a git pull. I have tested above scenario before I post, it worked for me :)