# Checkout to branch when git clone --depth 1 doesn't work

Tags: git, git-checkout

```
set -e
cd /source

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx.git

pushd ./ndn-cxx

git checkout -b release-build ndn-cxx-0.3.3

./waf configure

./waf

./waf install

popd

rm -rf ./ndn-cxx
```

I am running the above mentioned script, but getting the error: "Cloning 
into 'ndn-cxx'...
/source/ndn-cxx /source
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'release-build' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'ndn-cxx' which can not be resolved as commit?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git checkout on a remote branch does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, if you specify the `--depth` option, git will only fetch the master branch, so you won't be able to checkout to any other branch.

You can write the following :

```
git clone --depth 1 <url> --single-branch --branch <branch>
```

to retrieve the latest version of `<branch>` instead, like this:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx.git --single-branch --branch ndn-cxx-0.3.3
```

You won't have to do a `git checkout` after the clone

Answer (score 0):

As @edi9999 said above, `--depth` option fetches a single branch by default. If you want to fetch all other branches near the tip of the specified depth, you have to specify `--no-single-branch` option.

E.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx.git --depth 1 --no-single-branch
```